# Fixed width for columns in grid

Tags: views

I have a block with a 3-column grid view. The three products are next to each other on the left side. I cannot get them to use the full block width, so that each column has a fixed width, for example 33%.

I have searched for an answer the whole day. I tried some CSS adjustments, but I can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success with explicitly setting the width of the table that contains the images/titles.

Set the width of `<table class="view-view-grid cols-3>` to 100% in your CSS and see if that doesn't help.

Comment: Hmm, and what do i have to put in my style.css exactly for that? 

This doesnt work..
.view-view-grid cols-3 {
width: 100%;
}

Comment: I'd try targeting it with `table.views-view-grid`. So set `table.views-view-grid { width: 100%; }` Also, I assume you're referring to [this style sheet]: (http://www.bluraykopen.nl/sites/all/themes/sankofa/css/style.css)

Comment: worked! thx!!! :)